# Handling User Defaults, Menus and UI

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsuserdefaults

This is a conceptual question and I most definitely need some input.

**Here's the general (simplified) idea:**

- I have window layout, with a sidebar and a status bar
- The sidebar and the status bar are toggle-able
- The defaults are being registered at launch
- The current state, when any of them is toggled, is saved in `NSUserDefaults` (= YES / NO)

The toggle actions actually correspond to `NSMenuItem`s. So, their content *(e.g. "Show Sidebar" - "Hide Sidebar")* is actually "bound" to the corresponding value from `NSUserDefaults` and validated via `validateMenuItem:`.

Now, here's where it gets more complicated.

**When the application starts again :**

- We read the `NSUserDefaults`
- Is the sidebar `ON`?
- Depending on the actual design in the XIB (where the sidebar is visible), do nothing
- If it is `OFF`, then hide it.
- And so on...

Is that the "normal" way to go about this whole thing, or am I missing anything?

I'd be glad to hear your approaches!

Comment: Do you have some special code for handling launch? Is there something specific you're worried about with the approach?

Comment: Well, look... The project is quite huge (close to 50k lines and counting) so there's obviously LOTS of things going on. What I'm mostly worried about is over-complicating things, or - more precisely - not doing them the most cocoa-friendly way. *(To be honest, whenever I find myself writing too much code in Cocoa, it feels as if I'm doing something wrong and that I could have avoided it by binding everything together... automagically! LOL)*